# Lower Bounds on edge connectivity for expander graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

So I've been messing around with expander graphs, and since their advantage is to maintain a high 'connectivity' with a fixed degree, I wondered about their edge connectivity.

Formally, fix $k \ge 2$ and lets say we have a sequence of $c$-expander graphs $(G_n) = ((V_n,E_n))_{n\in \mathbf{N}}$ if it satisfies the followings :

- $|V_n| \longrightarrow +\infty$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$
- $G_n$ is $k$-regular for all $n$
- there exists a constant $c>0$ such as $h(G_n) > c$ for every $n$.

where $h(G)$ is the Cheeger constant defined as $$h(G) = \min_{W\subseteq V, |W| \le \frac{|V|}{2}} \frac{|\partial W|}{|W|}$$ and $\partial W = \{y \in V\backslash W | \exists x \in W, (x,y)\in E \}$

Is there a way to uniformely have a lower bound on the sequence of the edge connexity $(\kappa(G_n))$ ?
I actually have prooved $\kappa(G_n) \ge \min(k,c\cdot k)$ but that seems rather low in my opinion. Moreover the expander mixing lemma seems to give a lower bounds that tends to $-\infty$ which therefore isn't much interesting.

I have also wondered about a probabilistic approach on $2n$-expanders as there is an easy model based on permutations, and that may be easier to compute the number of indepedents path in probability, which then would give an estimate of $\kappa(G)$ thanks to Menger's theorem.

Does anyone have an idea of an approach for this question ?

Comment: Are you sure about $\kappa(G_n) \ge ck$? The best I can do is $\kappa(G_n) \ge \frac{c}{c+1}(k+1)$ (with some rounding). Furthermore, if $c>1$, then $\kappa(G_n) \ge ck$ can't possibly hold, because $\kappa(G_n) \le k$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually have $\kappa(G_n) \ge \min(k,ck)$ (I'll edit the post), by pointing out the fact that for any subset $A\subseteq V$ having $|A| < k$, there are at least $k$ edges going out of $A$, and then I use $\min |\partial W| \le \kappa(G)$ and the definition of the Cheeger constant to get the lower bound $ck$.

Comment: In that case, suppose we take an existing $c$-expander $G$, add a disjoint complete graph $K_{k+1}$, and modify it as follows: pick a random $\frac c2(k+1)$-edge matching in $G$, a $\frac c2(k+1)$-edge matching in $K_{k+1}$, and swap the two out for a $c(k+1)$-edge matching between the two components. Shouldn't that be very likely to give a new $c$-expander with connectivity $c(k+1)$?

Comment: According to some examples, as long as $\kappa(G) \not = k$ it indeed seems, I am trying to write down the math behind. This would mean that the bound is tight, as the process is infinitely repeatable, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Rather than infinitely repeating this process, I was thinking of starting with an existing infinite sequence of expanders, and making a new sequence by applying this construction to each one. The thing is, if the matching in $G$ is badly chosen, we could hurt the expansion of the result; I have the intuition that most matchings will work fine (though this needs proof!) but I wouldn't want to repeat this process forever in case the odds add up.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the aim here is to "minimize" the connectivity ? In any way, that seems to me to be true as well with high enough probability, I will be working onto that, thanks !